# How do you get func start to output versbose logs for azure functions

Tags: azure-functions

Running an azure function app locally how do you get debug level logs (trace, warning, debug as well as info etc).

Command used to run the local function apps:

```
func host start
```

Answer (score 1):

This turns on lots of logging:

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development \
  AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__default=Debug \
  AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logger__categoryFilter__defaultLevel=Debug \
  ENVIRONMENT=development \
  func host start --csharp --verbose
```

(p.s. `\` is a line continuation for those not familiar with bash, wrapped for readability but it's actually all one line)

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46201280/10245 for the `categoryFilter` bit.