While running an Azure function locally with `func start`, how do I see LogDebug and LogTrace messages
I started a container with mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 and installed the Azure Function tools following the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-csharp?tabs=linux%2Cazure-cli.  The instructions didn't work because their InRelease file was messed up, but I did manually download the package and install it.
My dotnet --version gives 8.0.403 and func --version gives 4.0.6280.
Once that was done, I used func new and selected 1. dotnet (isolated worker model), 1. c#-isolated, and 2. HttpTrigger.  Finally, I gave the function name MyFunction.
This gave me all the files I needed to run a function and it responds to http requests.
I then modified the constructor to add a LogXXXX() message for each of the levels I am interested in.  The resulting entire source file is:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace t4
{
    public class MyFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyFunction> _logger;

        public MyFunction(ILogger<MyFunction> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            logger.LogError("Testing Error");
            logger.LogWarning("Testing Warning");
            logger.LogInformation("Testing Information");
            logger.LogDebug("Testing Debug");
            logger.LogTrace("Testing Trace");
        }

        [Function("MyFunction")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}

If I execute this with func start or func host start and then trigger the function, I get the LogError, LogWarning, and LogInformation messages, but not the LogDebug, or LogTrace.
I tried modifying the hosts.json many different ways.
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        },
        "logLevel": {
          "Function": "Trace",
          "Function.MyFunction": "Trace",
          "Function.MyFunction.User": "Trace",
          "Functions.MyFunction": "Trace",
          "Functions.MyFunction.User": "Trace",
          "default": "Trace"
        }
    }
}

This has an effect on the other parts of the code, but not my function.  I expected the Function.MyFunction.User to have an effect, but it did not.  I threw the Functions* flavors in as a wild guess after seeing messages with that.
I also tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65688442/12195361 but had no different behavior.

Did you change program.cs?


I execute this with func start or func host start and then trigger the function, I get the LogError, LogWarning, and LogInformation messages, but not the LogDebug, or LogTrace.

I got the trace and debug logs also using below program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var rith_cho = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(ri_sc =>
    {
        ri_sc.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        ri_sc.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        ri_sc.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(rich =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule ri_tr = rich.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (ri_tr is not null)
            {
                rich.Rules.Remove(ri_tr);
            }
        });
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, ri_cfg) =>
    {
        ri_cfg.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hct, rilg) =>
    {
        rilg.AddApplicationInsights(rics =>
        {
            rics.IncludeScopes = true;
        });

        rilg.AddConfiguration(hct.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    })
    .Build();

rith_cho.Run();

host.json:
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Function.Function1": "Trace",
      "Function.Function1.User": "Trace",
      "default": "Trace"
    }
  }
  }

Function.cs is same as yours.
Output:


This at least gets me the messages, but the "Function.*" settings seem to have no effect.  I don't understand the code well enough to troubleshoot further and it really isn't worth the effort.  I just ended up changing all my .LogDebug() messages when debugging.
