# Azure function v 2.0 not showing verbose messages when logLevel is set to Debug

Tags: node.js, azure, function, debugging

I've been experiencing this issue since a couple of hours now.

> Context: I'm running an Azure Function `v2.0` project in `nodejs v12 LTS` and I'm using `VS Code Debugger` with the `--verbose` flag to debug my application

When I set the `logLevel` to `Debug` I never see the output of the `context.log.verbose` inside a function.

This is what my `host.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
      "logLevel": {
          "default": "Debug"
      }
  }
}
```

> PS: I'm not able to see the `verbose messages` too on the `App Insights` in the Azure portal

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `logLevel` to `trace` for `context.log.verbose` or you can use `context.log.info` with `Debug` `logLevel`.

After that is set correctly, you will be able to see the log in the App Insights. Example below:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

see this question [Azure function verbose trace logging to Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188052/azure-function-verbose-trace-logging-to-application-insights?rq=1)

Comment: Unfortunately, this only applies to `azure function v1.0` 
I'm talking about `v2.0+` any clue?

Comment: have you tried setting level to "Trace" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels , also check the 'traces' query in insights, you see the console.log output there, maybe 'context.log' will show up too

Comment: Awesome, I can see the logs in `VS Code` you saved my day.
My question now is: `how should I proceed in the Portal`?